# strcpy has no room for the null terminator, so what is it printing?

Tags: c, string, security

```
char buffer[8];
strncpy(buffer, "12345678", 8);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

prints: `12345678�`

I understand that the issue is that there is not room for the null terminator, and that the solution is to change the `8` to a `9`.

But, I am curious what it is printing and why it stops after two characters.

Is this a security flaw or just a bug? Could it be exploited by a user?

**EDIT 1**

I understand that officially it is undefined behavior and that nasal demons may occur at this point from a developer perspective, but if anyone has a good understanding regarding the actual code that is running, are there people who could exploit this code in a controlled manner. I am wondering from the point of view of an exploiter, not a developer, whether this could be used to make effective exploits.

**EDIT 2**

One of the comments led me to this site and I think it covers the whole idea that I am wondering about: http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen152_05/Lectures/BufferOverflow.html

Comment: Do you know [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)? BTW it stops at the first `'\0'` found in memory after `buffer[7]`

Comment: It can be exploited if the user fills the buffer yes. You can read about the dangers of `gets` and buffer overrun attacks.

Comment: @LPs thx for the info on why it continued beyond 8 and why it stopped when it did, this was definitely some of the information that I was looking for.

Comment: About security it depends on the implementation: what is allocated after `buffer`? What can be printed by `printf` manually removing null terminators after `buffer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way `strncpy` was designed and implemented. There is a clear warning which is mentioned in most of the man pages of strncpy as below. So, the onus is on the user to ensure he/she uses it correctly in such a way that, it cannot be exploited.

*Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.*

---

*But, I am curious what it is printing and why it stops after two characters.*

It is an undefined behavior! When you try to print a string using "%s", the printf function keeps printing characters in contiguous memory starting from the beginning address of the string provided till it encounters a `'\0'`. As the string provided by you is not null terminated, the behavior of printf in such a case cannot be predicted. It may print 2 additional characters or even 200 additional characters or may lead to other unpredictable behaviors.

---

*are there people who could exploit this code in a controlled manner*

Yes, Ofcourse. This can lead to printing of contents of memory which would otherwise be inaccessible / unknown to users. Now, how useful the contents of the memory is depends on what actually is present in the memory. It could be a private key or some such information. But, please do note that you need carefully crafted attacks to extract critical information which attacker wants.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to print something that is not a string by using `%s` in `printf`, the behavior is undefined. That undefined behavior is what you observe.

Function `strncpy`, by design, in intended to produce so called *fixed-width strings*. And that it exactly what it does in your case. But in general case *fixed-width strings* are different from normal *zero-terminated strings*. You cannot print them with `%s`.

In general case, trying to use `strncpy` to create normal zero-terminated strings makes little or no sense. So no, "the solution" is not to change `8` to `9`. The solution is to stop using `strncpy` if you want to work with zero-terminated strings. Many platforms provide `strlcpy` function, which is designed as a limited-length string copying function for zero-terminated strings. (Alas, it is not standard.)

If you want to print a fixed-width striung with `printf`, use format `s` with *precision*. In your case `printf("%.8s", buffer)` would print your fixed-width string properly.